# Setting default height on vim windows

Tags: vim, python-mode

I am using python-mode with vim and want to have the horizontal splits from the plugin show 17 lines of content.

In my .vimrc I've tried:

`autocmd BufEnter __run__ :resize (the difference of the current default.)`

Unfortunately this didn't workout the way I'd planned any suggestions.

Also if possible scaling with the amount of input up to the 17 line max would be the more preferred outcome, if technically possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put this in your .vimrc

```
set lines=17 " for height of the window
set columns=80 " for width of the window
```

for setting the window size

Comment: Thanks for the idea but this doesn't really achieve the result I'm looking for I orginally had in my .vimrc the following:

set winheight=9999
set winminheight=0

But this sets the overall hight of each windows and effect to many other plugins like NERDTree and Docs (for python-mode). Plus when I split horizontally these windows are sized incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

```
let g:pymode_quickfix_minheight = 3
let g:pymode_quickfix_maxheight = 6
```

if so, you can change the number based on your need.